# React-router-dom, useNavigate(-1) problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on countries project.
I get information about this when the `border` buttons are clicked. But when I click the `Back` button, the previous country data does not appear. How can I fix this? Please help me!

Here is my Country Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loading from './Loading';

function Country() {
    const { countryCode } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [country, setCountry] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => { getSingleCountryData(countryCode); }, []);

    const getSingleCountryData = async (countryCode) => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
          const country = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("countries")).filter(c => c.cca3 === countryCode);
          setCountry(country[0]);
          setLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }
  }

  return loading ? <Loading />
      : (
          <div className='country container'>
              <button className='btn backBtn' onClick={() => navigate(-1)}> Back </button>
                        
              // some code
                  
              <div className="country__borders">
                  <h4>Border Countries:</h4>
                  {country.borders && country.borders.map((border, index) => {
                      return <Link to={`/countries/${border}`} onClick={() => getSingleCountryData(border)} key={index} className='btn'>{border}</Link>
                  })}
              </div>
          </div>
      );
}

export default Country;
```

Comment: This piece of code is not enough to figure out the problem and suggest a solution. You should create a codesandbox to show your application in action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook is missing the `getSingleCountryData` and `countryCode` as dependencies. You'll want to memoize the `getSingleCountryData` callback so it's provided to the `useEffect` hook as a stable callback reference.

```
const getSingleCountryData = useCallback(async (countryCode) => {
  setLoading(true);
  try {
    const country = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("countries")) || [])
      .filter(c => c.cca3 === countryCode);

    setCountry(country[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  getSingleCountryData(countryCode);
}, [countryCode, getSingleCountryData]);
```

Since the `country` data is fetched and loaded when the `countryCode` route param updates there'll no longer be a need to trigger this fetching when the link is clicked.

```
{country.borders && country.borders.map((border, index) => (
  <Link
    key={index}
    to={`/countries/${border}`}
    className='btn'
  >
    {border}
  </Link>
))}
```

And since the data is not longer fetched via a click handler and only referenced in the `useEffect`, `getSingleCountryData` can be moved ***into*** the `useEffect` hook and be removed entirely as a dependency.

```
const getSingleCountryData = useCallback(, []);

useEffect(() => {
  const getSingleCountryData = async (countryCode) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const country = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("countries")) || [])
        .filter(c => c.cca3 === countryCode);

      setCountry(country[0]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
  getSingleCountryData(countryCode);
}, [countryCode]);
```